# Carrusel de Bostrap, no presenta la animacion,Crosfade ect

Tags: bootstrap

Estoy tratando de hacer una pagina web usando Bootstrap, llevo 2 días, pero directamente copiando el código del a propia documentación, y bueno en las vistas previas de esta, al hacer el cambio de imagen de el carrusel este no muestra ninguna animación de cambio, y claro ya tengo todo importado.

En la pagina tampoco puedo ver la vista  previa de estas animaciones, uso brave, pero también lo probé el algunos navegadores usando mi pagina, y tampoco puedo ver estas.

```
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-u1OknCvxWvY5kfmNBILK2hRnQC3Pr17a+RTT6rIHI7NnikvbZlHgTPOOmMi466C8"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Codigo del carrucel :

```
    <div id="carro" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-bs-ride="false">
        <div class="carousel-indicators">
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carro" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carro" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carro" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="mangas.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h5>First slide label</h5>
              AQUI SALE
              <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            PAN
            <img src="cyber2.webp" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." width="730" height="900">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h5>Second slide label</h5>
              <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            DE
            <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h5>Third slide label</h5>
              <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carro" data-bs-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carro" data-bs-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
      </div>
```

Codigo css

```
.carousel-item{

    height: 20rem;
    background-color: black;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: repeat;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Quizás estaría bueno que agregues el código que estás utilizando para tu carousel y cual es el efecto que esperas. Te sugiero leer [ask].
Debes agregar en tu pregunta al menos el mínimo código viable para poder probarlo y así poder realizar las pruebas pertinentes para ayudarte en el menor tiempo posible.
A priori de acuerdo a la documentación de react se puede agregar el efecto Crossfade agregando al carousel la clase "carousel-fade".

Comment: Ya te enseño el código que estoy realizando, también las imágenes por mas que use el css para darles backgroud-cover, ellas no se ajustan y pierden calidad de una manera terrible.

Comment: También mirando videos, intente darle directamente los valores ala imagen desde el html, como se puede ver, pero sigue sin cambios.

Comment: Se supone que al tomar directamente el código de la documentación, yo debería ya tener tanto el crossfade, como las imágenes  perfectas, cosa que no sucede, no tengo la animación de cambio de imágenes (Un desvanecido o un slide es lo que busco)

Comment: Puedes agregar un [repro] en la pregunta misma a través de un snippet (con el botón que indica `<>`) para que se pueda visualizar el problema, ya que los snippets soportan HTML + CSS + JS.